# Order of zero of a function

Tags: complex-analysis, roots

1) Suppose I want to find the order of the zero of the following function
$$ f(z) = (e^z - 1)^3$$
at $z=0$.

I first find the Taylor expansion for $e^z - 1$, and then write
$$e^z - 1 = zg(z),$$
where $g$ is analytic and $g(0) \ne 0$. Next, I say $f(z) = z^3 [g(z)]^3$, so it has a zero of order 3 at 0. Is that right? The reason I'm asking this is because in complex analysis, it is not true that $(z_1 z_2)^\alpha = z_1^\alpha z_2^\alpha$. If it's not right, is there any way I can do it fast without expanding everything?

2) How can I find the order of the zero of $f(z) = [\log(1 + \sin z)]^2$ at $z = 2\pi$ without applying the formula to the whole function $f$ to find the Taylor series? Will the multi-valued $\log$ function affect how I do it?

Thank you.

Comment: If $a$ is an integer, then $(z_1z_2)^a = z_1^a z_2^a$ even if $z_1$ and $z_2$ are complex.

Comment: @mrf Thank you. Do you have a reference for it?

Comment: A reference? It follows directly from $z^n = z\cdot \cdots \cdot z$ and the fact that multiplication is associative and commutative.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If we denote the $n$-th derivate of $f(z)$ with $f^n(z)$, then the following holds :

If $f(z)=0$ and $n$ is the smallest positive integer with $f^n(z)\ne 0$ , then the zero $z$ of $f(z)$ has order $n$.

Comment: Thank you for reminding me about that. If the order of zero is like 3 or 4, I have to take the derivative 3 or 4 times. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, exactly that.

Comment: Do we have a faster way because taking derivatives of a product and quotient many times may be a lot of work? For instance, can we generalize that if $f(z)$ has order of zero of 3, then $[f(z)]^2$ has order of zero of 6? Is that true? Thank you.

Comment: If we cannot extract the factor $(z-a)$ somehow (when $a$ is a root), no. If we have $g(z)\cdot (z-a)^n$ and $g(a)\ne 0$, then we immediately know that the order is $n$. You are right that $f(z)^2$ has order $2n$, if $f(z)$ has order $n$.